# NotificationListenerService get Notification Icon?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.3-jelly-bean

In a Service extending the new (SDK18, JB-4.3) `NotificationListenerService`, I'd like to get the Notification's status bar icon.

`mStatusBarNotification.getNotification().icon` returns the resource id of the status bar drawable, but that resource id is naturally not within my app's scope/resources. There's also `mStatusBarNotification.getNotification().largeIcon` (returning a `Bitmap`), but that's not set for all notifications and returns the "wrong" icon (the image in the expanded notification drawer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `getPackageName()` on `StatusBarNotification` to find out the app that posted the `Notification`. You can then [use `createPackageContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get a `Context` for that package, then use that `Context` to retrieve the image (e.g., via `getResources()`).

Comment: How does that work? setSmallIcon still requires a int resource ID, and using createPackageContext and getResources just gives me access to the Drawable itself.

Comment: @KyleJahnke: I do not know of a `setSmallIcon()` method that has anything to do with this question. Perhaps you are looking to create a `Notification`; this question is not about creating a `Notification`, but rather examining an existing one.

Comment: He's asking how to find the icon that the other notification had entered *into* `setSmallIcon()`;

`notification.extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON)`

Comment: @CommonsWare this didn't provide a  proper answer.

Comment: @NoumanCh: You used the technique that I provided (`createPackageContext()`) in your answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know perhaps how to get the image of the notification (like the person image in case it's from a chatting app) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have never used `StatusNotification`. I see where you can get the wrapped `Notification` from it, and presumably this data is inside of there. Whether that is available from public fields or is baked into a `RemoteViews` probably depends on OS version, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I got it: `notification.getLargeIcon()?.loadDrawable(this)?.toBitmap()` or  (I think it does the exact same thing as this ) `notification.extras.getParcelable<Icon>("android.largeIcon")?.loadDrawable(this)?.toBitmap()` .  Not sure though when it's null, when it's some placeholder, when it's the image from the address book, and when it's from the app itself. I guess it depends on the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the alternative workaround.

We can get drawable from `sbn.getNotification().extras.getInt("android.icon")` and then use customview to show this drawable in the notification.

This is how to get Drawable using android.icon value:

```java
            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_push_notification);
            contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, notificationModel.getTitle());
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, notificationModel.getBody());
           

            try {
                   //now get the context of other app and then get drawable from resoures
                    Drawable drawable1 = context.createPackageContext(notificationModel.getPackageName(), CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY).getDrawable(notificationModel.getIcon());
                    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable1);
                    contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, bitmap);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My `notificationModel` is:

```java
notificationModel.setKey(sbn.getId());
```