# Get notification's icons Android

Tags: java, android

Can anybody help me to get notification's icons? I'm using `AccessibilityService` for pre 4.3 devices and `NotificationListenerService` for 4.3+. I don't know how to use the method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044067/5193581).

Thanks!

Comment: I get an error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" when running this on NotificationListener

Comment: You're going to have to give us some code, *I'm using <something>* just is not enough. Where do you access it and how do you call it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I only want a way to get the icon of the notification fow now.