# How to get notification icon of other app?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm using NotificationListenerService for catching notification, with the help of [kpbird blog](http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html). But I'm unable to extract the icon's drawable. I'm also going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044044/notificationlistenerservice-get-notification-icon), but things are not cleared to me. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

To get other application icon, just get package name of that application and use below code. You will get package name from notification instance.

```
String pack= "com.whatsapp" // ex. for whatsapp;
        Context remotePackageContext = null; 
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {  
            remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);  
            Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(id);  
            if(icon !=null) {  
                bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

Comment: where is id coming from?

Comment: Here 'id' is Icon resource id that you can get from notification object.

Comment: For example :-  Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(notification.icon);

Comment: Thanks @SaadBinIqbal ! important to note that this code should use `statusBarNotificationInstance.getNotification().icon` and not `statusBarNotificationInstance.getId()`

Comment: This will get the icon from the application, not the icon shown in the notification.